# os.command giving Attribute error

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to rum a C *.o using python 2.6.5 as follows

```
import os
import sys
file_type = os.command('./file_type.o %s.txt 2>&1' % file_name)
```

And, it gives the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'command'
```

Being a beginner this might be a very trivial question, I request for the direction / help.

Comment: Where did you read that `os.command()` is the way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function named `command` in the `os` module, hence the error.  You probably meant to call [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`os.command()` doesn't exist. It looks like you are looking for [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

Answer (score 1):

os.command doesn't exist, using os.system instead.